# Running a program with multiple arguments from list using parallel

Tags: bash, shell-script, command-line, gnu-parallel

I have a bash program that I run via command line (Ubuntu) like this:

```
./extract_field.sh ABC001
```

where `ABC001` is the field ID that I want to extract from a given shapefile.

To run this script with multiple IDs, I first save one ID per line in a `list.txt` file:

```
ABC001
ABC014
ABC213
ABC427
```

and then invoke the script using `parallel`:

```
parallel -a list.txt ./extract_field.sh
```

So far so good.

However, I plan to change `extract_field.sh` so it takes two arguments rather than only one. Will the above workflow still work if I just change my text file to accommodate two arguments per line like this?

```
ABC001 arg2a
ABC014 arg2b
ABC213 arg2c
ABC427 arg2d
```

With this change, I would expect `parallel -a list.txt ./extract_field.sh` to behave like

```
./extract_field.sh ABC001 arg2a
./extract_field.sh ABC014 arg2b
```

and so on.

Is that right?

I could just test it before asking, but I decided to ask first since this change in the script will probably take me a couple of hours to finish (though it sounds like a simple change).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can provide multiple arguments to a single command with parallel by specifying a column delimiter in your command syntax
To use your example:

```
parallel --colsep ' ' -a list.txt ./extractfield.sh {1} {2}
```

Will provide the result of

```
./extract_field.sh ABC001 arg2a
./extract_field.sh ABC014 arg2b
```

Given that your file `list.txt` contains

```
ABC001 arg2a
ABC014 arg2b
```

You can test this with `cp` or `mv` since these both require multiple positional parameters.

[Useful bit of parallel's manpage](https://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html#EXAMPLE:-Use-multiple-inputs-in-one-command)

Comment: Alsp try `--dry-run`.